# Having more than one value being set within a component in JSF

Tags: jsf

i have a Selectonemenu like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu 
    id="canal" 
    tabindex="1"
    value="#{actionCadastrarPropostaFiliaisOrigemNatura.idCanal}"
    label="#{msg.selecione}" 
    required="false">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{actionCadastrarPropostaFiliaisOrigemNatura.canais}">
    </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Can i set more than one value within it? Like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu 
    id="canal" 
    tabindex="1"
    value="#{actionCadastrarPropostaFiliaisOrigemNatura.idCanal},#{actionCadastrarPropostaFiliaisOrigemNatura.idCanal2}"
    label="#{msg.selecione}" 
    required="false">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{actionCadastrarPropostaFiliaisOrigemNatura.canais}">
    </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If i can't, how can i set more than one value in my managedbean class?

Comment: Consider using a UISelectMany-based control instead of a UISelectOne-based control.

Answer (score 0):

Set one value directly and two indirectly like this:

**JSF**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.valueToSetDirectly}">
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class Bean {

    private String valueToSetDirectly;
    private String firstValueToSetIndirectly;
    private String secondValueToSetIndirectly;

    public String getValueToSetDirectly() {
        return this.valueToSetDirectly;
    }

    public void setValueToSetDirectly(String valueToSetDirectly) {
        this.valueToSetDirectly = valueToSetDirectly;
        this.firstValueToSetIndirectly = valueToSetDirectly;
        this.secondValueToSetIndirectly = valueToSetDirectly;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but is there a way that i can get the value before the init method?